# Fourier Transformation of $e^{-|t|}\cos(2t)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation, fourier-transform

> **Q.** Fourier Transformation of $f(t) = e^{-|t|}\cos(2t)$?

Why can't I say $f(t) = e^{-(-t)}\cos(2t)u(-t) + e^{-t}\cos(2t)u(t)$ and then use scaling property?

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Scaling ($a$ real)}
& f(at)
& \frac{1}{|a|} F(\frac{\omega}{a})
\\
\hline
\hspace{4em} \vdots \hspace{4em}
& \hspace{6em} \vdots \hspace{6em}
& \hspace{4em} \vdots \hspace{4em}
\\
\hline
\text{15}
& e^{-at}\cos(\omega_0 t) u(t), \ a > 0
& \frac{a+j\omega}{(a+j\omega)^2+\omega_0^2} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{align*}

After doing that why doesn't it work when I use **#15** and then the scaling property.

$$ F(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+(\omega-2)^2} + \frac{1}{1+(\omega+2)^2} $$

The answer is above and below is what I'm getting

[image: OP's answer]

---

- [Original image 1 - Scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfKII.png)
- [Original image 2 - Formula #15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XUQ4.png)
- [Original image 3 - The Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBzZq.png)

Comment: Please use latex and/or parenthesis to clarify the exact exponent here. Also what is the "scaling property"?

Comment: updated  @AlexR.

Comment: well you can they should give you the same result @Andrew

Comment: Both are the same: $$\frac{1}{1+(\omega-2)^2} + \frac{1}{1+(\omega+2)^2} = \frac{2(\omega^2+5)}{\omega^4-6\omega^2+25} = \frac{1-j\omega}{4+(1-j\omega)^2}+\frac{1+j\omega}{4+(1+j\omega)^2}. $$